# K&R's exercise 2-6: Do not understand input/output

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

K&R's exercise 2-6:

> Write a function `setbits(x,p,n,y)` that returns `x` with the `n` bits that begin at position `p` set to the rightmost `n` bits of `y`, leaving the other bits unchanged.

Here is my interpretation of an example input/output:

```
unsigned x = 315;
int p = 2;
int n = 3;
unsigned y = 9;
printf("%d\n", setbits(x, p, n, y));  // 295
```

And here is my reasoning.

3 bits at position 2 for 315:

```
0000 0001 0011 1011
             - --
```

3 rightmost bits for 9:

```
0000 0000 0000 1001
                ---
```

Set 3 rightmost bits for 9 to the 3 bits starting at 2 for 315 => 295:

```
0000 0001 0010 0111
             - --
```

I wrote some code and then wanted to check it against other solutions, [for example](http://www.eng.uerj.br/~fariasol/disciplinas/LABPROG/C_language/Kernighan_and_Ritchie/solved-exercises/solved-exercises.html/krx206.html). The two that I found online both give a different answer, 313:

```
0000 0001 0011 1001
                --- ???
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Indexing starts at zero in C. Presumably, "position 2" is the third bit.

Comment: Without a [mcve], it is not possible to diagnose your code.

Comment: Okay, I was wondering about that and tried both ways. I've edited my question to reflect the correct positioning, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Olaf, I'm actually just asking about input/output. What about my reasoning for what the *expected* answer should be is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification of the problem is a bit ambiguous. You are interpreting
"the n bits starting at position p" to signify bits p, p+1, ..., p+n-1.
The page you linked to seems to say the n bits starting at position p
are bits p, p-1, ..., p-n+1.
So the 3 bits starting at bit 2 would be bits 2, 1, 0, the rightmost three bits.